# Http get request with Observable and bidirectional binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

The code a do an HTTP call and return an `Observable<PersonModel>` (a single value not an []). I put the result in a variable in `myPersoneModel`. I'd like do a bidirectional data binding (to do an http post later). I got on error depending the `[(ngModel)]` syntax I use in `<input type="text">`.

Do you have an idea ?

```
export class SpecialityModel {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    constructor(
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string){
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}

getPerson(id:number): Observable<PersonModel> {
    let apiURL = `http:............/person/${id}`; 

    return this.http.get(apiURL) 
      .map((res: Response) => res.json().response);
}
```

In the Component :

```
private myPersonModel: PersonModel;

ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getPerson(5).subscribe( data => {
        this.myPersonModel = new PersonModel (data.lastName, data.firstName);
    });
}
```

In the template:

When I do this : `<input [(ngModel)]="myPersonModel.firstName">`
*I see the value but in the console I get some errors : 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]*

When I do this : `<input [(ngModel)]="myPersonModel?.firstName">`
*I don't see the value and I get this error :
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 27 in*

Thanks,

Comment: You can use `async` pipe with `myPersonModel.firstName` to bind the data because the Observable works asynchronously so when `ngModel` looks for the property to bind the value, it  does not exist.  So you can use `[(ngModel)]="myPersonModel.firstName | async" by importing async pipe. Where have you declared `this.myPersonModel` in your code?

Comment: But using Elvis operator(?.) with two way binding `ngModel` is not supported yet in Angular 2.  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7697 . So the  second approach won't work

Comment: @Niladri I use angular6 I tried the async pipe but same result.

Answer (score 2):

As one person mentioned, the service request is asynchronous. To fix your issue, you can initialize myPersonModel in your component where you declared it. For example `private myPersonModel: PersonModel = new PersonModel('','');` .

Your other option would be to use the Elvis operator. Something like `<input [ngModel]="myPersonModel?.name" (ngModelChange)="myPersonModel.name = $event" />`.

Or just wrap the input in an `*ngIf="myPersonModel"`.

Comment: I search to solve the problem not find a workaround. Imagine If I have a model with 10 properties...

Comment: I think this is a good response. No need to downvote it, just because it's not what you hoped to hear because it's not possible

Comment: In fact two-way data-binding can be confusing and bad for performance, which is why it can be linted-out with codelyzer. It's a good practice to use regular bindings instead.

Comment: @Phil  what is the best solution for you? I'd like understand "Eric M" answer $event.